# Postfix with Clamd

Tags: email, postfix, clamav

I've been setting up my own VPS for an e-commerce, as well as a mail server.

In order to setup the e-commerce, `mysql` and `apache` is running.

In order to setup the mail server, I've installed `postfix`. However, after installing postfix, several days passed and I figured out something:

- Some mails are delayed / blocked because of `ClamD` email checks.
- `ClamD` is using about 50% of my VPS resources. I've checked if those values were normal, and a lot of users complain about the same.
- The easy way, would be to remove `ClamD` / Stop it. However I do not want to keep an unsafe mail system.

I'm not very used in setting up mail environments, so I'm looking for tips about:

- What happens if I do not use antivirus for those mail checks?
- Is there an other good enough antivirus to check for those mails?
- In case I decide to not use any antivirus, should I setup some grey/blacklisting in order to prevent spam sent / received?

Sorry if my question is a little bit abstract.

Comment: What's your primary function of your mail server? Receiving or Delivering?

Comment: Both. However just handles 2 email accounts, with less than 100 mails per day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the OP comment, the mail server only handle 2 email accounts. For a small system like this, you can safely turn off the `clamD`. In this situation, I prefer to alternative solution like educate your user about email security rather than place an antivirus daemon to scan your email. Antivirus will help you in the system with many user involving and you can't educate them one by one.

Instead on virus, another challenge you faced is spam. The solution like properly-configured `postfix` and external solution like grey/blacklisting (via `postgrey` for example) will help you reduce spam in with little cost on system performance.